# Perl - parsing huge *.gz file in Windows

Tags: perl, parsing, gzip

I'm trying to parse big *.gz file using Perl in Windows.

In Solaris I'm able to use following construction:

```
my $cmd = "zcat $dir/$file|";
open FILE, $cmd or die "$cmd:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
.
.
.
}
```

and it works fine.
In Windows I'm tring to use [IO::Zlib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aZlib) module, e.g.

```
my $fh = IO::Zlib->new("$file", "rb");
while (my $line = $fh->getline()) {
.
.
}
```

but I'm running out of memory. (I have 4GB RAM on my system). Is there any other method to parse big *.gz file?

Comment: Why can't you just unzip it before processing? Running out of disk space?

Comment: Do you do something else with the lines inside the loop? Also, if your file has foreign line endings, perl may slurp the file (IO::Zlib uses explicit `\n` instead of `$/`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just install [Gzip for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm) (which includes `zcat`)?  Aside from the memory issue you're having, I've found that piping from `gzip` is faster than using `IO::Zlib`.  (There's a couple reasons for that.  `$fh->getline` is a method call, and Perl's method calls aren't the fastest.  Also, running `gzip` externally takes advantage of multitasking, which can be noticeable now that multi-core machines are common.)

For some reason, GnuWin provides `zcat` as a shell script, which doesn't really work under Windows.  But you can use `gzip -cd` instead of `zcat` (that should work on Unix platforms, too).

Comment: hmm, sounds good. I will try it. Do you think you can tell me, how to do piping from gzip in windows?

Comment: The same way you did it on Solaris.  You just have to have `zcat` on your `PATH` (same as Solaris).

Comment: I have installed GnuWin32, can see zcat in bin directory, updated PATH, but I don't know how to call zcat in perl script. Still getting error message 'c:/progra~1/GnuWin32/bin/zcat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: my $cmd="c:/progra~1/GnuWin32/bin/gzip.exe -cd $file|"; did the trick for me :-). Thank you very much for the nice tip

Comment: Trying to read the zcat filehandle will still slurp in the whole file if the file contains Unix newlines on Windows.  `$/` must be altered to match the `\012` newlines in the file.  Unless that wasn't the problem in the first place.

Comment: @Schwern, that's simply not true.  On Windows, `$/` defaults to `\012` just like it does on Unix.  The difference is that Perl applies the `:crlf` layer by default on Windows.  That transforms CRLF line endings into LF, but Unix-style LF-only line endings are passed through unchanged, and work just fine.

Comment: Huh, I did not know that!  Wacky.  I retract my comments.  It does explain why @taiko had problems after converting the file to DOS newlines.  I'll bet the CRLF transform was not being applied inside IO::Zlib.

Answer (score 2):

`IO::Zlib->getline` is going to read in a "line".  A line is defined as a bunch of data ending with the end of line.  Perl's "\n" changes according to the operating system.  On Unix (including Solaris and OS X) this is 012 (the newline character).  On Windows this is 015 012 (carriage return + newline).

If your file has Unix newlines, `IO::Zlib->getline` will be looking for Windows newlines when you run it on Windows.  It will try to read the entire file into memory.  Normally you could fix this by setting `$/`, the "input record separator" aka "what is the end of a line" to be `\015\012` but IO::Zlib (via [Compress::Zlib](https://metacpan.org/module/Compress%3a%3aZlib#GZIP-INTERFACE)) does not support `$/` for backwards compatibility reasons.

Fortunately, all this mess was rewritten as IO::Compress and IO::Uncompress.  Using [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aUncompress%3a%3aGunzip), which you should already have installed as its what supplies Compress::Zlib...

```
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;

# A block to isolate the local $/
{
    my $fh = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($file);

    # the file being read has Unix newlines
    local $/ = "\012";

    # As an added bonus, the object works as a filehandle.
    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: While this should work, the last time I benchmarked it on gigabyte-sized files (which was years ago) it was significantly slower than opening a pipe to an external `gzip` process (presumably for the reasons I mention in my answer).  Even when using the object as a filehandle, Perl's still using method calls under the hood.

Comment: @cjm The OP didn't ask which was fastest, they asked why it wasn't working.  Using zcat doesn't solve the newline problem, `<FILE>` will still slurp the whole file in if its using Unix newlines on Windows.  `$/` must still be modified.  If you want micro-performance, we don't know what the OP is doing with the lines, use the C program.  If you want cross-environment compatibility, use the Perl module.  Since they're working on both Solaris and Windows I presume cross-environment is important.  YMMV.

Comment: Actually, using an external `gzip` *does* solve the newline problem.  On Windows, Perl applies the `:crlf` layer by default, which accepts either CRLF or LF line endings as input (transforming the former into plain LF).

Comment: Thanx for tanother idea. Maybe I should mention, that before I used the input file I have converted it to dos using unxi2dos cmd in Solaris, wouldn't this address the newline issue? I will your approach anyway, just to compare whats better. thanx a lot again

Comment: Concerning the purpose of the script, I'm parsing the lines with regexp , getting some info and inserting it into database.